Turning my Computer as a server to Host Rails 8 App
I am new to rails framework. I have a thinkpad T14 Gen3 computer with Ryzen7 processor, 32GB RAM and 512GB SSD. I am running Ubuntu 24 LTS on it. I want to use this PC to deploy simple rails app build on Rails 8 using Kamal in Rails 8. Any suggestions or a way forward. Thanks in anticipation.
